# 4k 60Hz over usb-c not working, OSX Macbook Pro 2017?

Tags: mac, display, external-display, 4k-resolution

I recently connected a 4k 60Hz monitor to my macbook pro 2017 (touchbar), and OSX. I could not get it to display at 4k 60Hz. Any advice.

My monitor is Asus PA328Q and I am using the apple usb-c to HDMI, USB3, USB-c dongle.

Answer (score 4):

I found an answer after a bit of work. This is what I learnt.

The standard usb-c dongle from apple does not support HDMI at 4k 60Hz. This is the standard dongle that has usb-c charging passthrough, USB3, and HDMI.

This HDMI from this dongle is maximum 4k 30Hz. (Actually, at the moment 4k 60Hz over HDMI seems like a new-standard, and the majority of USB-C to HDMI adapters DO NOT SUPPORT THIS as default)

After learning this, I purchased a usb-c to display port adapter, this should work for most people, however this did not work when I first plugged this in. So try that first.

**Then a series of annoying things happened that are particular to my particular display, but I will post them here in case it helps others.**

For my PA328Q, you can only access the onscreen menu IF THERE IS A CORRECT INPUT displaying. So I could not access the menu at all when my Display port cable was plugged in. When I plugged it in the first time, my screen flashed as if something was being transmitted, my mac identified the display, and I could even mirror/extend etc. as if it was working. However the screen was black. Even using **cscreen** in terminal saw it there.

The fix was to plug back in the HDMI at 4k 30Hz, go into the menu, then scroll down on the menu to extra settings to **more** at the bottom, go into **system setup** then **display port stream** and then select **DisplayPort 1.2**. Then, after doing this, unplug the HDMI, and then plug in the usb-c to display port cable and then WOOP, it works.

So in summary, get onscreen menu by using whatever output works, turn on Display Port 1.2, then go back to display port.

Hope this helps others. This was a huge pain working out, as I purchased multiple cables to try to pin down the issue!

Answer (score 0):

I discovered you can get a USB-C Cable that supports the video signal (which, as you noted, the cable included with the Macbook Pro does not). I'm using [this cable](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B071LB53PN). It still does not power the Macbook Pro, though.

Answer (score 0):

Using Macbook Pro 2018. Worked through this issue myself just now. 60Hz was not supported with HDMI connection (display options would only go up to 30Hz). Tried the recommendations switching the DP setting to 1.2 and using Display Port rather than HDMI. Still didn't support 60Hz.

Here's the weird fix that finally worked for me:

Connected both an HDMI cable and a Display Port cable (i.e. used two USB-C ports, one for each cable). Made sure DP 1.2 was selected in monitor settings. Chose Display Port as input. Voila, 60Hz works at full 3840x2160 resolution.